# Is there memory leakage when reassigning a variable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

Suppose I have a variable that's already been initialized to a string via an alloc/init combination.  Will I have memory leakage if I reassign it via processing, ie.

```
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:someOtherStringVariable];
s = [s stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Has there been memory leakage here?  If so, do I need to create another variable (e.g. s2), do this assignment, and then release the original?

```
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:someOtherStringVariable];
NSString *s2 = [s stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
[s release];
```

Now, what if the some other string is a constant, like @"Some other string".  Would I need to worry about leakage? ie.

```
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Some other string"];
s = [s stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is definitely a leak. The easiest way to take care of issues like this is to autorelease sooner rather than later:

```
NSString *s = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Some other string"] autorelease];
s = [s stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

You could also use NSMutableString to do this as well, in place (if this isn't a notional example).

Comment: Thanks.  The example was notional as you point out.  I thought I had read somewhere that there is memory allocated for the string literal in any case, so it would never be released.  So it's retain count was irrelevant.

Comment: It's true that you don't have to release/manually memory-manage string literals. However, in your code you don't assign a string literal directly, but rather do [NSString alloc] before. As soon as you have an alloc you need an (auto)release. This won't leak: NSString* s = @"Some string"; s = [...];